# how to make my current page on the navbar a different color?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make it so that the current page I am on, the button on the navbar is a different color and shape. I have tried using the 'current' property and the 'active' property but it doesn't work. i am using Replit, so I don't think it's compatible with it.

Here's the link:
https://replit.com/@TomWalkington1/my-website-1#style.css

Comment: This has been asked before. I suggest that you do a search and also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please also post your code **in your description** not a link (use the `<>` button - it creates a runnable snippet). The style you linked will be fixed eventually so people cannot learn from your question. I'm sure you found StackOverflow by stumbling upon someone elses question and someones answer to it. Your post might be important for someone else so please treat it that way yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I would add a class to the active `<a>` tag and style that class with css.